# Swapping the binding on a ListBox when selecting a ViewModel in a List of ViewModels in Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I have a list of ViewModels each of which contains a list.

I want to bind this list to a ListBox in the view, so that I can set a `SelectedViewModel` and the ListBox in the view now shows the entries in the new `SelectedViewModel`. This should also preserve selection.

**Is it possible to do this with the current Caliburn Micro conventions or do I have to explicitly state this?**

For example:

I have a list of ViewModels called `vmList` containing two ViewModels, `Fruit` and `Veg`.

The ViewModel `Fruit` contains the list `["Apple", "Pear"]`.

The ViewModel `Veg` contains the list `["Carrot", "Cabbage"]`.

`Fruit` is the current `SelectedViewModel` so my view's ListBox currently should show:

```
Apple
*Pear*
```

`Pear` is currently the selected item in the ListBox.

Now I set `Veg` as the `SelectedViewModel` and my View updates to show:

```
*Carrot*
Cabbage
```

`Carrot` is currently the selected item in the ListBox.
Now if I set `Fruit` back to being the `SelectedViewModel` my View should update to show:

```
Apple
*Pear*
```

Where `Pear` is still the selected item in the ListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible - the simplest functionality for this would be using CMs conventions to bind the list content, and also supplying a `SelectedItem` binding for the list. Since you want to track the last selected item in each VM, you need to keep tabs on that too (either in the VMs themselves or in the main VM)

So the solution could be:

```
public class ViewModelThatHostsTheListViewModel
{
    // All these properties should have property changed notification, I'm just leaving it out for the example
    public PropertyChangedBase SelectedViewModel { get; set; } 

    public object SelectedItem { get; set; }

    // Dictionary to hold last selected item for each VM - you might actually want to track this in the child VMs but this is just one way to do it
    public Dictionary<PropertyChangedBase, object> _lastSelectedItem = new Dictionary..etc()

    // Keep the dictionary of last selected item up to date when the selected item changes
    public override void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if(propertyName == "SelectedItem")
        {
            if(_lastSelectedItem.ContainsKey(SelectedViewModel))
                _lastSelectedItem[SelectedViewModel] = SelectedItem;
            else
                _lastSelectedItem.Add(SelectedViewModel, SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="SelectedViewModel" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Obviously set your item template here to bind to a common property on the viewmodels (such as `DisplayName` using `IHaveDisplayName` interface to keep things nice and integrated)

Edit:

Just a quick note: if your VMs themselves aren't `List` objects and instead contain a list, then you might have to bind the list items explicitly to the `ListBox` but it depends on your `ItemTemplate` (you can get CM to keep resolving VMs and Views for VMs based on `ContentControl` convention bindings)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedViewModel.ListItems}" ...etc />
```